# Grails persistence in Spring's "Async" annotated methods not working

Tags: spring, grails, service, asynchronous

I have a problem on persisting Grails domain objects in Spring Async annotated service methods.

Here is the simplified code:

```
class DocumentService {

@Async
def process(Long documentId, Organization organization) {

    ...

    def organizationCari = new OrganizationCari(organization: organization, active: true)
    organizationCari.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

    print "Document processing..."

    ...

    print "Document processed..."


}
```

}

I have the method running asynchronously, but then I can't seem to get anything printed on the console, since thread ends upon save operation. I get no errors and the domain object is still not persisted.

Removing Async annotation solves the problem, but I have to run the method asynchronously.

I'm using Grails 2.1.1 with Spring 3.1.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that there is no hibernate session in the new asynchronous thread, and the default `AsyncTaskExecutor` is not logging the exception.

You can verify this yourself by putting a `try/catch` block inside your `@Async` method and logging the exception yourself.

The solution is to use `Domain.withNewSession` around the GORM code in your service method:

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async

class MyService {

    @Async
    void myAsyncMethod() {
        MyDomain.withNewSession {
            MyDomain m = new MyDomain(...)
            m.save()
        }
    }
}
```

If you have many asynchronous methods, you may consider creating your own `AsyncTaskExecutor` as in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9045776/459743).