# RestControllerAdvice @ExceptionHandler(value = Throwable.class)

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Hi i have one question

```
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
  @ExceptionHandler(value = Throwable.class)
  public ErrorResponse handleException(final Throwable ex) {
    LOG.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    return new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(),
        ex.getClass().getSimpleName(), "An internal error occurred");
  }
```

Is this exception handler is only for synchronous calls to some service from Rest Controllers. If I have some asynchronous tasks(spring managed? Ex: @Async methods), and exception occurs, most probably the exception will not be propagated here. Is it true?

or I should use Thread.setDefaultExceptionHandler()

Comment: How do you bubble up the exceptions? All bubbled up to controller layer?

Comment: This is the problem, not every exceptions is bubbled in the controller layer. And I'm not sure how to proceed..

Comment: When you say asynchronous tasks, are they spring managed? Ex: @Async methods? or non-spring async tasks?

Comment: spring managed -> @Async methods

Comment: Ok, please add that info in the question. Also, have you tried `AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler` ? good answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735870/spring-async-uncaught-exception-handler